# Error when add custom line in TOC (\cftaddnumtitleline in memoir)

Tags: macros, table-of-contents, memoir

I try to add custom line in TOC. I use `\cftaddnumtitleline` as described in memoir manual

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}

  \tableofcontents*

  \cftaddnumtitleline{toc}{section}{1. }{First}{\thepage}
  First text
  
  \cftaddnumtitleline{toc}{section}{2. }{Second}{\thepage}
  Second text 
\end{document}
```

I expect, that I will see the section-like entries in TOC. But instead I got:

[image]

How should I fix it? Or is there other way to add custom TOC line?

**UPDATE**: It seams like a memoir bug that affects latest version:

- memoir 2021/03/23 v3.7o   *bug does not exist*
- memoir 2022/07/29 v3.7r   *bug exists*
- memoir 2022/11/17 v3.7.19 *bug exists*

Comment: I just copied your code and run it `pdflatex` `pdflatex` on Windows 10 TexWorks (with TeXlive 2021) and cannot replicate your image [(this is how mine compiles)](https://imgur.com/H58kwe9). Can you include more details on your system, TeX version etc please?

Comment: Tried in overleaf and got the same result https://overleaf.com/read/vyppwstgwrbr

```This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2022.8.9)  10 FEB 2023 15:06
entering extended mode
 \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**main.tex
(./main.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-06-01> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2022-08-05> (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/memoir/memoir.cls
Document Class: memoir 2022/07/29 v3.7r configurable book, report, article document class
```

Comment: On local setup `This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.15.0 (TeX Live 2022)  (format=lualatex 2023.2.5)  10 FEB 2023 14:51
 restricted system commands enabled.
 Document Class: memoir 2022/11/17 v3.7.19 configurable book, report, article do
cument class`

Comment: Mine is: `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2021/W32TeX) LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-05-11>
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/memoir/memoir.cls
Document Class: memoir 2021/03/23 v3.7o configurable book, report, article docu
ment class`. Sorry then, there must have been an update between the `memoir` versions or something, mine is 2021 v3.7.0. I can reproduce the issue on Overleaf too, hopefully someone can help!

Comment: Very strange. On my first LeTeX run of your MWE on a ubuntu systemI get a ToC that looks normal, but on a second run, without changing any code, I get your result. I gave up maintaining memoir some years ago and have no idea what might be causing this. Apologies.

Comment: My memory is certainly not what it was but I have a vague recollection  that some time ago the LaTeX kernel code was updated. Perhaps the kernel and memoir coders weren't synchronized. (It's always good to blame someone else!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that appears to work on Overleaf, add this command to the preamble:

```
\renewcommand{\cftaddnumtitleline}[5]{%
  \addtocontents{#1}%
    {\protect\contentsline{#2}{\protect\numberline{#3}%
                              {\protect\ignorespaces #4}}{#5}\newline}}
```

I added the `\newline` at the end of the command after `{#5}`. It produces this (on Overleaf):

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\renewcommand{\cftaddnumtitleline}[5]{%
  \addtocontents{#1}%
    {\protect\contentsline{#2}{\protect\numberline{#3}%
                              {\protect\ignorespaces #4}}{#5}\newline}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents*

\cftaddnumtitleline{toc}{section}{1. }{First}{\thepage}
First text
  
\cftaddnumtitleline{toc}{section}{2. }{Second}{\thepage}
Second text 
\end{document}
```

The original command looks like this (after going [on CTAN for `memoir`](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/memoir) and finding the `.dtx` file):

```
\newcommand{\cftaddnumtitleline}[5]{%
  \addtocontents{#1}%
    {\protect\contentsline{#2}{\protect\numberline{#3}%
                              {\protect\ignorespaces #4}}{#5}}}
```

I have no idea what broke for your TOC to look like that, way above my understanding, but for the maintainer there was an update for the kernel as [@Peter Wilson](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/12082/peter-wilson) pointed out in the comments that corresponds with my version working (v3.7o) and then your version containing the bug (3.7r).

```
% \changes{v3.7o}{2021/03/23}{Maintenance and a provide for the kernel}
% \changes{v3.7p}{2021/06/16}{Small adjustments of memoir vs memhfixc}
% \changes{v3.7q}{2022/02/20}{Maintenance}
% \changes{v3.7r}{2022/07/29}{Maintenance}
% \changes{v3.7.19}{2022/11/17}{Maintenance}
```